# Not able to fetch all XML tag values using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm trying to fetch xml node of one attribute. But its not fetching properly

here is my response

```
def response = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
     <tem:getMotorPremium><tem:objUserDetails>                
         <ns:ProductCode>2311</ns:ProductCode>   
         <ns:ProductId>2311</ns:ProductId>   
         <ns:ProductName>2311</ns:ProductName>   
        </tem:objUserDetails></tem:getMotorPremium>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm getting values each in the following way.

```
def code = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
                       .Body
                       .getMotorPremium
                       .objUserDetails
                       .ProductCode
                       .text()

def Id = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
                       .Body
                       .getMotorPremium
                       .objUserDetails
                       .ProductId
                       .text()

def Name = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
                       .Body
                       .getMotorPremium
                       .objUserDetails
                       .ProductName
                       .text()
```

I dont want to use "new XmlSlurper().parseText(response).Body.getMotorPremium.objUserDetails" all the time

I've used something like this to try, but its not working.. Kindly advice

```
def ab = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response).Body.getMotorPremium.objUserDetails
    logInfo("Product code :"+ab.ProductCode.text());
    logInfo("Product Id :"+ab.ProductId.text());
    logInfo("Product Name :"+ab.ProductName.text());
```

Comment: The code you provided works well. Which version of groovy are you using?

Comment: @Opal I'm getting as empty string for those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works perfectly fine:

```
def response = """
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
     <tem:getMotorPremium><tem:objUserDetails>                
         <ns:ProductCode>2311</ns:ProductCode>   
         <ns:ProductId>2312</ns:ProductId>   
         <ns:ProductName>2313</ns:ProductName>   
        </tem:objUserDetails></tem:getMotorPremium>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
def ab = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response).Body.getMotorPremium.objUserDetails
println("Product code :"+ab.ProductCode.text())
println("Product Id :"+ab.ProductId.text())
println("Product Name :"+ab.ProductName.text())
ab.with {
    println("Product code :"+it.ProductCode.text())
    println("Product Id :"+it.ProductId.text())
    println("Product Name :"+it.ProductName.text())
}
```

Maybe this is `logInfo` problem?

Comment: I will check again and will confirm u

Comment: Got it.. Sorry there was a typo.. Thanks Opal